# Change font in iOS share extension pop up

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, ios8-share-extension

I have created a working share extension to share a URL, and am using the default share extension pop up. Now, I'd like to change the bar button font of the iOS share extension pop up. I have tried both of the following attributed text commands in the ShareViewController viewDidLoad() without success:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.classForCoder() as! UIAppearanceContainer.Type]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSFontAttributeName: newFont], for: .normal)
```

and

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"OfficeCodeProD-Regular", size: 12)!]
```

Any suggestions or pointers towards the appropriate resources is much appreciated!

Comment: Your approach is very "hacky" and it's usually a bad idea to forcefully changing non-changeable attributes in system elements. If you want a custom share pop-up, you should create a custom view.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know.

Comment: I don't think you can change the appearance of, what is in effect, a system controlled window. You would probably be better off just making your own UX for your extension. I wanted to change the button titles, and approached it this way. It was pretty simple.